# Windowed operation + multiple aggregation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID'      : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
'Country' : ['IT', 'AL', 'US', 'IT', 'AL', 'FR', 'EN', 'AL', 'CH'],
'Month'   : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
})
```

```
   ID Country  Month
0   1      IT      1
1   1      AL      2
2   1      US      3
3   2      IT      1
4   2      AL      2
5   2      FR      3
6   3      EN      1
7   3      AL      2
8   3      CH      3
```

What I'm looking to do is adding a column that contains the country the object was in during the last month (3 in this case but could be different for each group). Namely:

```
     ID Country  Month  EndCountry
    0   1      IT      1  US
    1   1      AL      2  US
    2   1      US      3  US
    3   2      IT      1  FR
    4   2      AL      2  FR
    5   2      FR      3  FR
    6   3      EN      1  CH
    7   3      AL      2  CH
    8   3      CH      3  CH
```

What I am actually looking for is to have it aggregated. But once I have this table it's easy to aggregate. Anyway in case somebody has a one-step solution I give also my final wanted result

```
    ID EndCountry TotalSales
       1     US        X
       2     FR        Y
       3     CH        Z
```

Where TotalSales is an other column in which I make a different aggregation e.g. sum of a column Sales.

Once the first table is obtained the final result can be obtained via

```
df.groupby('Month').agg({'EndCountry':'max','Sales','sum'})
```

I have tried building my own custom aggregation function but the function receives a single column as input so it cannot aggregate based on the value in a different column.

Comment: Use `last` in the aggregation: `df.groupby('ID').agg({'Country': 'last', 'Sales': 'sum'})` should be what you want

Comment: `df=df.assign(EndCountry=df.groupby('ID').Country.transform('last'))` will give you the first output. if that helps

Comment: This works as long `df` is sorted by `ID` and `Month`

Comment: In your example there is no a column called `Sales`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a fix to the comments already made. 
If you want to know the "EndCountry" you can follow [@anky_91's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775014/windowed-operation-multiple-aggregation-in-pandas#comment100105644_56775014). But taking the last works only if the `Month` column is sorted.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'ID'      : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
'Country' : ['IT', 'AL', 'US', 'IT', 'AL', 'FR', 'EN', 'AL', 'CH'],
'Month'   : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
})

df = df.sort_values(["ID", "Month"])\
       .reset_index(drop=True) 

df["EndCountry"] =  df.groupby("ID")["Country"]\
                      .transform('last')
```

It's not quite clear to me how can you add sales of one `ID` if in your table you're tracking the position of the same object over the months.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick thanks! What is not clear about adding sales? I have the sales month by month and I want to have the total per year along with where the thing is at the end of the year. After getting the result you obtained (of course with the Sales column that I omitted) it is a simple aggregation.